# dict key insert and update key value pair in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
"SOCIAL_MEDIA": {"google": "abcdef123456789101112131",
               "insta": "abcdef12341yHlmOrR8D3vlV1cD2VtL7k9xk9DSB8vw="
               }
```

Enter Key:
`"SOCIAL_MEDIA"`

Enter value:
`"facebook": "98765432181bbe3a2596efa8ba7abcde"`

The output will like:

```
"SOCIAL_MEDIA": {"google": "abcdef123456789101112131",
               "insta": "abcdef12341yHlmOrR8D3vlV1cD2VtL7k9xk9DSB8vw=",
               "facebook": "98765432181bbe3a2596efa8ba7abcde"
               }
```

Comment: `dict['SOCIAL_MEDIA']['facebook']=value_you_want`

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need something like this:

```
import json

input_data = '{"SOCIAL_MEDIA": {"google": "abcdef123456789101112131", "insta": "abcdef12341yHlmOrR8D3vlV1cD2VtL7k9xk9DSB8vw="}}'
parsed_data = json.loads(input_data)
parsed_data["SOCIAL_MEDIA"]["facebook"] = "98765432181bbe3a2596efa8ba7abcde"
output_data = json.dumps(parsed_data)

print(output_data)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the point of json? Is this not the comment I posted above?

Comment: I need a script which contains 2 input, Enter your key and enter your value first input should be like my key social_media in 2nd input should be like key value pair  "facebook":"uifosja;ljk'tlrs" and it insert into that social_media dict. using this script I can add n number of key value pair.